# OPC Compliance error [M4.1] error related to incorrect user file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have faced with a problem that when I am trying to import my excel file in program I am getting the next error:

```
OPC Compliance error [M4.1]: there is more than one core properties relationship in the package !
```

There is a lot of suggestions about this issue. One of the is just copy past all data to the new file and it does the trick.(It does)

But I have a lot of files and I cant just recreate all of them before import to the program.

I am importing xls. and .xslx files using Apache-POI version 3.5-FINAL(pretty old I know it, but I have to work with it).

Is there any suggestions to not recreate file? Maybe it some configuration in OS Windows can help ?

Comment: Upgrade to a newer version of Apache POI?

Comment: Why do you have to work with POI 3.5?